# Use Array on Countif - To Count occurrence of Array items

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

In Excel is there a way without VBA to use an Array formula to count the occurrence of each item in a list?

If you use count, sum and if you must specify the exact names to be used, which would be unrealistic in most scenarios.
[Microsoft Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-how-often-a-value-occurs-aa1f3067-05c9-44e4-b141-f75bb9bb89bd)

How could I get the count of each items occurence in this list with an Array formula?

```
Names
Bill
Jill
Phil
Lil
Bill
Will
Phil
Frank
Lil
John
Ron
John
Phil
```

Comment: maybe `{=Sum(--(A2:A99="Bill"))}` or `=SumProduct(--(A2:A99="Bill"))` or PivotTable

Comment: You could also have a look at the frequency formula in combination with remove duplicates.

Comment: @Slai          close you can use =SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$14=A2)) and then copy down and you will get the count of each entry, it of course doesn't remove duplicates but the count of each entry is correct.